# How to paginate a query?

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I need to paginate a query in Wordpress.

I have for example a query like this:

```
$query = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_db WHERE id = '1'");
```

And I print the result like this:

```
foreach ( $query as $query_print )   { 
echo $query_print->id."<br>";
}
```

For example this query extract 4 records and I want to divide this record in 2 pages (2 records for page).

Comment: What exactly do you want to paginate, show us the query, not a fake one? You could probably use the actual WP-Query class which has built-in pagination.

Comment: It is a query on a custom table created by my in the Wordpress database, I want to extract it and paginate but I can not do it.

Comment: You'd need to keep track of how many results you show per "page" then create your own pagination which basically looks at the current step plus how many you want to show. I'm not able to write an example at the moment but will in a bit.

Comment: Thanks your for your reply Kyon147; could you please write an example when you have the possibility ?